# $(f_n)$ a Cauchy sequence in $C[-1,1]$ in the $||\cdot||_1$ norm? $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ norm?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the sequnce of  functions $(f_n)$ in $C[-1,1]$ defined by $f_n(x)=x^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$

Is $(f_n)$ a Cauchy sequence in $C[-1,1]$ in the $||\cdot||_1$ norm? Why?

Is $(f_n)$ a Cauchy sequence in $C[-1,1]$ in the $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ norm? Why?

So my attempt to prove it's Cauchy in  $||\cdot||_1$ norm:

$||f_n-f_m||_1=\int^1_{-1}x^{1/(2n+1)}-x^{1/(2m+1)}dx=\frac{x^{1/(2n+1)+1}}{1/(2n+1)+1}-\frac{x^{1/(2m+1)+1}}{1/(2m+1)+1}=$ $ \frac{(2n+1)x^{\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}}}{2n+2}\Big|^1_{-1}-\frac{(2m+1)x^{\frac{2m+2}{2m+1}}}{2m+2}\Big|^1_{-1}=\frac{2n+1}{n+1}-\frac{2m+1}{m+1}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty,m\to\infty$

So the sequence is cauchy

For the $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ norm:

$||f_n-f_m||_{\infty}=1$ So, it's not Cauchy

Would this be correcT?

Comment: How did you decide that $\|f_n - f_m\|_{\infty} = 1$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom well the max that $f_n(x)=x^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$
 can take is $1$? So the difference would be maximized when $f_n$ is $1$ and $f_m=0$?

Comment: Why do you say that $\|f_n-f_m\|_1=\int^1_{-1}x^{1/(2n+1)}-x^{1/(2m+1)}\,\mathrm dx$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos isn't this the $||\cdot||_1$ norm?

Comment: @ThePoorJew You need to take the absolute value of the integrand

Comment: @Omnomnomnom oh okay

Comment: @ThePoorJew Note that $\|f_n - f_m\|$ is equal to $\max_{x} |f_n(x) - f_m(x)|$, not $\max_{x,y} |f_n(x) - f_m(y)|$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom okay, thanks, i see

Comment: @ThePoorJew The conclusions that you have come to, however, are correct: the sequence is indeed Cauchy relative to the $1$-norm and fails to be Cauchy relative to the $\infty$-norm.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom so is the only thing I have to consider in my calculations are the absolute values, otherwise that's the correct way (my way) how to prove it?

Comment: @T Yes. Other than the issue with the absolute value, the approach you have taken for proving that the sequence is Cauchy relative to the $1$-norm is correct